# CSS offset but keep full width

Tags: html, css

I have a background which fills the screen, when I get to 1234px I want to position the background image a little more to the left and a little bit further down, but when I use background-position to offset like this :-

```
background-position: right 20px bottom 40px;
```

I get whitespace where it is pushing the background away. Is there a way to resolve this? Here is my css class:-

```
    .full-background{
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
             background: no-repeat;
 background-position: bottom center;
 background-origin: content-box;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url('assets/img/background.png');
 min-width:100%;
 position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: First check the syntax you use for [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) (the one you used in above code is wrong), than I suggest you use bigger image, which is on mibile view at: `-20px -40px`, but on desktop at '0 0';

Comment: I don't think there is a way to resolve this as cover will always make the image the size to fit on the screen perfectly in one dimension (either width or height) so moving it will always produce some white space.  The only thing I think you can do is use a media query and use a different image that is positioned as you want it

Comment: You can try to increase background-size to 105~110% instead of 'cover'.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element, like this

```css
.bkg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bkg::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10%;
  top: -10%;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/400/nature/1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {  /* add your min-width here */
  .bkg::after {
    left: calc(-10% + 20px);
    top: calc(-10% + 40px);
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="bkg"></div>
```